# How to use "event.target.value" & "event.target.checked" together in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few input fields few are type text and few are type checkboxes how can i get all the fields value together right now i'm able to only one at a time like given below example:-

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

I'm not able to use both together. Whats wrong with it?

Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: May I ask why do you want to have one common handler? It might make it less maintainable.

Comment: I think you should check for a particular type and accordingly set state instead of calling like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked ?? event.target.value });
```

Or explicitly test for the property existence:

```
if('checked' in event.target) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
}

if('value' in event.target) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend having a single handle, like what will be a good design practice>

Comment: @jaybhatt well I don't see any counterpart. It's just a very generic function to update the state with an input name and its value, whatever the input type is (and wrap native HTML oddities), I don't see any reason not to use it if there is no more logic to implement.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a conditional statement depending on the input type property. The `checked` property is only used with `<input type=checkbox />`

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: 
  event.target.type === 'checkbox' 
    ? event.target.checked 
    : event.target.value 
});
```

Comment: and `type="radio"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties_that_apply_only_to_elements_of_type_checkbox_or_radio